# Как можно хранить/описывать объекты

Tags: java, c++, моделирование

Стоит задача написать некую среду для моделирования. В ней пользователю предложены какие-то готовые модельки и алгоритмы. Но есть идея предоставить пользователю возможность самому написать модельку со своими алгоритмами, встроить ее в среду и посмотреть на результат. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать и как такое возможно реализовать.

Для большей ясности, вставлю пример, что хотелось бы получить.

Вот, допустим, есть в программе модель некоторого аппарата, который двигается как-нибудь поступательно. В программе можно будет задать параметры моделирования, прогнать аппарат и посмотреть на результат. Пользователь решил придумать свою модель, которая движется, например, по спирали, и такой модели в программе нет. Каким образом можно дать возможность пользователю реализовывать таким образом модели и, получается, встраивать их в программу ?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, о чём речь. О 3d-моделировании или о моделировании программной логики.

Comment: Среда предполагается для математического моделирования. Речь о том, как пользователю вставить свою собственную мат модель в готовую программу, разумеется, предполагается, что все интерфейсы соблюдены.

Comment: В wolframalpha так можно делать. Не то? https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/Math.html Опишите пожалуйста детальнее суть вопроса, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначный ответ.

Comment: Попробую на примере. 
Вот, допустим, есть в программе модель некоторого аппарата, который двигается как-нибудь поступательно. В программе можно будет задать параметры моделирования, прогнать аппарат и посмотреть на результат. 
Пользователь решил придумать свою модель, которая движется, например, по спирали, и такой модели в программе нет. 
Каким образом можно дать возможность пользователю реализовывать таким образом модели и, получается, встраивать их в программу ?

Comment: Я понял ваш вопрос и боюсь, что не достаточно квалифицирован чтобы на него отвечать, но скажу что думаю :) Предположим, вы строите модель космоса и небесных тел. В ней каждая звезда/планета - это объект со своими параметрами. И пользователю даётся возможность добавить что-то своё уникальное. Например, чёрную дыру. Как ту быть?.. Чёрную дыру можно классифицировать как обычное небесное тело, просто её параметры (гравитация, масса) превышают норму. Значит нам нужно лишь дать пользователю больше свободы в интерфейсе проектирования - больше параметров, меньше ограничений в их значениях.

Comment: Не думаю, что хорошей идеей будет давать возможность пользователю реализовывать свои классы; классы должны быть предопределены, но их параметры должны быть гибко настраиваемыми.

Comment: Я уверен, что не сказал ничего нового/полезного для вас, просто ваш вопрос слишком абстрактный.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв ! Именно идеи подхода мне и нужны :) Идею сделать гибкий интерфейс отложил пока на крайний случай. Может, все-таки существуют какие-то методы/средства, чтобы такое реализовать.